# What is the index hook for configure product page

Tags: whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

i am trying to find the index hook of this button  "continue" in this url "/cart.php?a=confproduct&i=0".

according to the following list [index hook](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks/hook-index/), i want to find the index corresponding.

[image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uucRJ.png)

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the hook of ShoppingCartValidateCheckout.